# AJAX response is being cached

Tags: jquery, ajax

Once again I am posting the question similar to previous one but this time my problem is different. As said the code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: 'sample.php',
            data:"data="+data,
            success: function(server_response) { 
            $('.functions').ajaxComplete(function(event, request){

              if(server_response == 0)
                 {
                            var message = 'An email with instructions to reset password has been sent to your email address. Please check it.';
                 }
              else if(server_response == 1)
                {
                            var message = 'Email address was not found in our database. Please enter a valid email address';
                }
              else
                {
                            var message = 'Some problem occured while sending you an email. Please try again.';                                    
                }
   alert(message);

    });
```

The problem is whenever I pass an ajax request the server response received is correct but if above code is executed for multiple times without page refresh multiple dialog boxes are recieved in a stack order. Like if my first response is 0 then the message "An email with instructions to reset ...." is recieved. However if I send the request again without page refresh and this my if my page response is 1 then 2 dialogs are generated with message "Email address was not found in our database." on top and the previous one below. Such stack continues to generate until I refresh the page. I have tried all things such as setting cache to false and all stuff but all in vain. please help.

Comment: I am sorry but nothing posted here seems to solve my problem

Comment: Hello, my problem is I want to get rid of the stack generated. And only show the current message.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative pass `cache: false` in the jquery ajax options like as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            cache: false,
            url: 'sample.php',
            data:"data="+data,
            success: function(server_response) { 
            $('.functions').ajaxComplete(function(event, request){

              if(server_response == 0)
                 {
                            var message = 'An email with instructions to reset password has been sent to your email address. Please check it.';
                 }
              else if(server_response == 1)
                {
                            var message = 'Email address was not found in our database. Please enter a valid email address';
                }
              else
                {
                            var message = 'Some problem occured while sending you an email. Please try again.';                                    
                }
   alert(message);

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

2 ways for you:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false,
});
```

OR

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            cache: false,
            url: 'sample.php',
            data:"data="+data,
            success: function(server_response) { 
            $('.functions').ajaxComplete(function(event, request){

              if(server_response == 0)
                 {
                            var message = 'An email with instructions to reset password has been sent to your email address. Please check it.';
                 }
              else if(server_response == 1)
                {
                            var message = 'Email address was not found in our database. Please enter a valid email address';
                }
              else
                {
                            var message = 'Some problem occured while sending you an email. Please try again.';                                    
                }
   alert(message);

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact issue on a site being viewed through an iOS device.  It was somehow steamrolling the

```
cache: false
```

setting.  So I fixed it with a tried and true hack:

```
var d = new Date();
$.ajax({
    url : "blah.php?"+d.getTime(),
    cache: false,
    ...
```

I hope this helps anyone else facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

POST requests are never cached.

Try $.post instead

```
$.post('sample.php', {"data="+data}, function(server_response) { 
      if(server_response == 0)
      {
              var message = 'An email with instructions to reset password has been sent to your email address. Please check it.';
      }
      else if(server_response == 1)
      {
             var message = 'Email address was not found in our database. Please enter a valid email address';
      }
      else
      {
             var message = 'Some problem occured while sending you an email. Please try again.';                                    
      }
});
```